# Using FileStream to write to a file first time after the file is created gives an exception

Tags: c#, wpf, file

I am trying to write some json text. But I get an Exception like 
The process cannot access the file C:\blah blah\SystemInActivity.json because it is being used by an other process. But then second time when I run the app after  json file is created and then when I write I dont get an exception. Please help.

```
class ApplicationSettingsViewModel
    {
        ApplicationSettingsModel model;
        MemoryMappedFile mmf = null;
        public string FullPath = string.Empty;
        //This is not a singleton class but I guess it has to be one but its ok for demonstration.
        public ApplicationSettingsViewModel()
        {
            model = new ApplicationSettingsModel();
            CreateFileWithoutMemoryMap();
            //MemoryMapped();
        }

        public string GetDriectory()
        {
            return Path.GetDirectoryName(FullPath);
        }

        private void CreateFileWithoutMemoryMap()
        {
            var info = Directory.CreateDirectory(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData) + "/" + model.Data.Settings.OrcaUISpecificSettings.TimeOutFolder);
            string path = Path.Combine(info.FullName + @"\" + model.Data.Settings.OrcaUISpecificSettings.File);
            //mmf = MemoryMappedFile.CreateFromFile(path, FileMode.CreateNew, "MyMemoryFile", 1024 * 1024, MemoryMappedFileAccess.ReadWrite);
            FullPath = path;
            if (!File.Exists(path))
            {
                File.Create(path);
            }
        }

        public void WriteToFile(string json)
        {
            try
            {
                FileStream fileStream = File.Open(FullPath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite); //This line giving Exception
                fileStream.SetLength(0);
                fileStream.Close(); // This flushes the content, too.
                using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(FullPath))
                {
                    sw.Write(json);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }
        }
```

In the constructor of the MainWindow I am calling the write method

```
private ApplicationSettingsViewModel AppViewModel;
public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            //MessageBox.Show("App Started");
            AppViewModel = new ApplicationSettingsViewModel();
            WriteToFile("Active");

        }
public void WriteToFile(string status)
        {
            var root = new Root();
            string jsonString = string.Empty;
            root.AllApplications.Add(new DataToWrite() { AppName = "DevOrca", Status = status });
            try
            {
                jsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(root, Formatting.Indented);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(jsonString);
                MessageBox.Show("Exception");
            }
            mutex.WaitOne();
            //Serialize Contents and write
            AppViewModel.WriteToFile(jsonString);
            //var access = AppViewModel.GetAccessor();
            //byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(jsonString);
            //access.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
            mutex.ReleaseMutex();
        }
```

Comment: Your code does not guarantee the `FileStream` will be closed. Use a `using` block. Your `try/finally` is wrong. Never swallow exceptions.

Comment: Did you try a [simple search for that error message](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%23%5D+The+process+cannot+access+the+file++because+it+is+being+used+by+an+other+process)?

Comment: Never trust yourself, if you can use a `using` statement use it

Comment: Yes I know the try catch was wrong. I didn't worry about because I knew where the exception was coming. I can fix it later.

Comment: Thanks Ken White for the link provided. I will make sure to use a using statement wherever needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`File.Create()` method opens `FileStream` to create a file and you need to close it, something like this:

```
File.Create(path).Close();
```